# How to pause a component, when another becomes active?

Tags: reactjs, stopwatch

i am making multy timers, they all work okey. I can start, pause and resume each of them, but i need timers to pause when i press start on one of them. So, when one is active and I press start on the second one, the first one should pause automatically.

I don`t understand how to do this at all

```
render() {
 return (
  <div className='timer__inner'>
    <button onClick={this.newTimer}>add timer</button>
       {this.state.items.map(item => (
         <Timer key={item.id} />
       ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@peterjd42/building-timers-in-react-stopwatch-and-countdown-bc06486560a2

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, you have to keep the state in the parent component of all those timers and maintain an array of timers. Also, maintain the index of `currentlyPlaying`   timer in the state. So, when you start another timer, you can simply stop that timer using the index and keep a record of the index of new timer bein played.

So the state of parent component will look something like this:

```js
this.state = {
...
currentlyPlaying: -1; // Index of the currently playing timer.
Alltimers: [];
...
}
```

Now, when you play another timer and about to set the state, do this:

```js
startTimer(...) {
...

let currentlyPlaying = this.state.currentlyPlaying;
this.stopTimer(currentlyPlaying)
this.setState({currentlyPlaying: newIndex}) // You can fetch newIndex throug argsument.

... // Start the current timer.    
}
```

Make sure you do this in the parent component, in order to access the state. If you are managing the states separately in each timer, create a function to update `currentlyPlaying` inside parent and pass it to your timers.